# HRegionServer cannot communicate with HMaster

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, sasl

I have a 3-node Hadoop cluster (master and 2 slaves) with Hbase installed. Zookeeper and HMaster were installed on the Hadoop master node. After I started HBase Cluster by calling `start-hbase.sh`, the HMaster and the 2 HRegionServer processes were started.

However, the HBase cluster showed:

> "Waiting for region servers count to settle..."

When I checked the log file on slaves, it showed an error message as

> "Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will
>   not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)"

Not sure what that meant. I guess that the HRegionServer was trying to connect to localhost instead of the master node, which had the Zookeeper and HMaster installed. I have confirmed that communication between Master and Slaves through SSH was working either way, and all the physical IPs were correctly defined in /etc/hosts files.

Can any of you point out what could went wrong to interrupt the communication from HRegionServers to HMaster?

Comment: Update: I've figured out the cause of the issue. A letter in the HBase-site.xml was typed in with upper case, which prevented the HRegionServer from finding the hbase master. Problem solved!!!